# Is spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead deprecated?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

The explanation about `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` was disappeared on running-on-yarn.html document since Spark 2.3.x.

- Spark 2.2.3: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.3/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties
- Spark 2.3.0: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/running-on-yarn.html#spark-properties

I found new `spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead` property since Spark 2.3.0. But, according to the explanation, it is an alternative property of spark.yarn.**driver**.memoryOverhead, not of spark.yarn.**executor**.memoryOverhead.

Can't I increase memoryOverhead of spark executor? Or did the memory model of Spark executor change?

I have increased spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead to prevent being killed by YARN due to exceeding memory limits.

Comment: I checked https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html, looks like it is called spark.executor.memoryOverhead

Comment: Thank you! That would be the answer. I think the property was move to `spark.memory.*` from `spark.yarn.*` due to Kubernetes support. (Is my guess right?)

Comment: I confirmed that `spark.executor.memoryOverhead` property make YARN allocate more memory in Spark 2.4.4. Thank you.